# Conditional format cells based on match in another sheet

Tags: ms-office

I have 2 excel sheets (Using Microsoft excel 2011 for mac)

```
sheet1(Column D)
foo
bar

sheet2
abc cde foo
sfd sdf dgf
bar
```

I have applied 3 rules using conditional format: 1. If any of the data in Sheet2 matches with Sheet1(ColumnD) - Make text as blue 2. If there are any duplicate values in sheet2 - Make text as yellow 3. If the above 2 are not there - leave it blank

But Only Rule2 and Rule3 are working. How can I make all of them work.And I how can I add one more rule which returns values which satisfies both Rule1 and Rule2

Rules:

```
Rule 1 # =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($1:$1048576,'Sheet1'!$D:$D,0)))
Rule 2 # Highlight Duplicate values with yellow text
Rule 3 # =ISBLANK($1:$1048576)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I am parsing the problem correctly, but I suspect this is the solution.

Make a new column in one of the pages that has a formula like...

`=IF(thispage!D2=otherpage!D2,"*","")`

This will make a column where all the duplicates have a *. Now simply make a conditional on the other column that turns the text yellow if there is a * in there.